# what characters are not allowed in sqlite3 string without adding additional stuff

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, string, node-sqlite3

For example:
I want to insert a value which is a string
but the string contains a single quote (hello'world)
what I meant when I say 'adding additional stuff' 
is you have to add two quotes (hello''world)
so it becomes valid
I want to know all character like that or all character that doesn't need 'additional stuff'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This overriding of native SQL queries can be prevented by using prepared statements. Use the `prepare()` method.

Example from the `sqlite3` package [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) modified to your use case:

```
var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
stmt.run('hello"world');
stmt.run("hello'world");
stmt.finalize();
```

Safely inserts both `hello"world` and `hello'world` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will never have taught of this